# How can I make the following code more efficient and faster through C#?

Tags: c#

When the number of orgList is 2,000,000, it takes about 4 seconds.

Is there a faster way?

```
List<MyData> tmpList = (from data in orgList
                        group data by new
                        {
                            data.Date,
                            data.Name,
                            data.Number,
                            data.Birthday,
                            data.Major
                        } into grp
                        select new MyData
                        {
                            Date = grp.Key.Date,
                            Name = grp.Key.Name,
                            Number = grp.Key.Number,
                            Birthday = grp.Key.Birthday,
                            Major = grp.Key.Major,
                            Value1 = grp.Sum(x => x.Value1),
                            Value2 = grp.Sum(x => x.Value2),
                            Value3 = grp.Sum(x => x.Value3),
                            Value4 = grp.Sum(x => x.Value4),
                            Value5 = grp.Sum(x => x.Value5)
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: This might be better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since it's working code. If this is just plain C# then it's likely looping through for each `Sum` (i.e. looping through 10,000,000 items total for the `Sum` values), so doing it without LINQ would probably be faster. If it's LINQ to SQL then you ought to check the generated SQL.

Comment: Either way there is not a lot you can do to make this faster, apart from put it in memory and do the summing in one pass. or if on a DB, index the feilds appropriately

Comment: It's not bad for 2 million rows. But if this query is used for reporting purpose, then you should use some data warehousing technique to extra the data into a different database. Otherwise it will slow down your live DB.

Comment: You can refactor this into a loop with running totals or using the .Aggregate(...) an chain the results allowing for a single pass.  you are currently looping 5 times per key combination.